# .Datatable is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, datatable

I try this table feature
https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/scroll_xy.html

i have dropdown and date picker so i add links for table and datetime picker links then i add table and also i use script for this but when i select datetime picker then calendar is not display then when i check console this show error

I try to export table data in excel

```
WebForm1.aspx:34 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).Datatable is not a function
```

CODE

```
 <%--for tabledata--%>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"   src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

     <link rel="stylesheet"  href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />


        <link href="Styles/stylechart.css" rel="stylesheet" />
       <!--for date--%>-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

     <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#tabledata").Datatable({
                    dom: 'Bfrtip',
                    buttons: [
                        'excelHtml5'

                    ]
                });
            });

    </script>

        <table id="tabledata"   cellspacing="0"  class="display nowrap inner_table">

           </table>
```

**updated:**

```
     success: function (result) {
                    var final = JSON.parse(result.d).response;
                    console.log(JSON.parse(result.d).response);
                    $("#tabledata").empty();
                    if (final.length > 0) {
                        $("#tabledata").append(
   "<thead><tr><th>RegNo</th></tr></thead>");
                        for (var i = 0; i < final.length; i++) {

                            if (final[i] !== null) {
                                $("#tabledata").append("<tbody><tr><td>" +                    
                                 final[i][0] + "</td> </tr></tbody>");

                            }
                        }                    
                    }
```

Comment: `DataTable` !== `Datatable`

Comment: Here is a [live example](https://jsfiddle.net/sbr8efgw)

Comment: @Peacefull this is without links?

Comment: @user6628729 sorry but i don't understand what do you mean "without links" ?? Can you be more explicit please.

Comment: i means sources script links like this .. <script type="text/javascript"  src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

you are using multiple references of jquery file.Also order is more important for any plugin to work properly.
Also try to avoid writing protocol http or https before script reference , just add simple // and it will automatically detect on which protocol your app is working and load reference file according to it.

change your reference section to scripts like given below.

```
<link rel="stylesheet"  href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
<link href="Styles/stylechart.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!--for date--%>-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />

<script type="text/javascript"  src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"   src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#tabledata").Datatable({
                dom: 'Bfrtip',
                buttons: [
                    'excelHtml5'

                ]
            });
        });

</script>

<table id="tabledata"   cellspacing="0"  class="display nowrap inner_table">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Column1</th>
<th>Column2</th>
<th>Column3</th>
<th>Column4</th>
</tr>
</thead>
</table>
```

Comment: When i try your solution this show error on console.. jquery.dataTables.min.js:65 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'aDataSort' of undefined

Comment: Because you need to add data to your table. You use Json data ?

Comment: so your original error is gone now, it had issue of jquery and was not able to create datatable at all. now you have configuration error.

Comment: add columns inside your tabledata html table, which you want to see. for ex. you  predefine columns in gridview. look my answer i have edited it.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
         $('#tabledata').DataTable({
            sDom: 'TC<"clear">lfrtip',
            "iDisplayLength": 10,
            "oTableTools": {
      ***add*** "sSwfPath": "//cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.0/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
                "aButtons": [
                    "copy",
                    "csv",
                    "xls",
                    {
```

Comment: this not display copy csv and xls button